# Error when running java command raspberry pi

Tags: java, raspberry-pi

When I run

```
java --version
```

or any other java command on my raspberry pi I get this error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Server VM is only supported on ARMv7+ VFP
```

I tried to run

```
java --version
```

and I expected the java version to be returned but I got the error

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Server VM is only supported on ARMv7+ VFP
```

(using a raspberry pi b+)

Thanks!

Comment: how did you install java?

Comment: @drum sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk

Comment: try this? https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=212040